# TYPO3 + DCE - display image thumbnail in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using TYPO3 6.2 and the extension DCE (dynamic content elements).

Everything works fine, except that I wasn't able to display a thumbnail for the custom content elements in the backend.

For the frontend I use this fluid template:

```
    <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
        <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
            <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" width="140px"/>
        </f:if>
    </f:for>
```

It works fine. But if i use the same code for the backend (in the field "Bodytext preview template (fluid)") it doesn't output anything. What could be the reason for this?

By the way, what is a more elegant way to output just the first image? I guess I wouldn't have to use this for loop then?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you need to refer to "fields" instead of "field" in the backend previews

```html
<f:if condition="{fields.image}">
  <f:for each="{fields.image}" as="fileReference">
    <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" width="140px"/>
  </f:for>
</f:if>
```